# checked keyword for checking specified number of bits in c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Can we use checked in C# for checking overflow for a particular number of bits, like say 25, 30, etc.

```
int A = 0;
int B = 1000;

checked 
{
   A += 1000000; 
   B = B * A; 
}
```

For example, in the above example, can A be checked for 27 bits overflow.

Comment: Please provide some information about what your problem is. Your question seems to be more of a solution than the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing like that supported in C#.

The closest you could probably come would be to write your own method which used the "normal" type of overflow checking (32 bits for `int`, 64 for `long` etc) and then *also* imposed some extra restrictions on the valid values.

Ideally, I'd suggest creating your own wrapper type for this, e.g.

```
public struct Int25
{
    private readonly int value;

    // Constructor etc, and operators which always make sure the result
    // is within the appropriate range
}
```